# ModelMultipleChoiceFiled and initial values

Tags: django

My form:

```
class AdjustOffersForm(forms.Form):
    min_payout = forms.DecimalField()
    max_payout = forms.DecimalField()
    verticals = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Vertical.objects.all())
```

View:

```
offer_settings, created = OfferSettings.objects.get(id=id)
form = AdjustOffersForm(initial={
        'min_payout': offer_settings.min_payout,
        'max_payout': offer_settings.max_payout,
        'verticals': offer_settings.vertical,
    })
```

I'm not getting initial values in the form. If I choose some options from the form and then save it, the information are stored in the database successfully. But if I try to restore previously selected values in the form I can't get them.

What is the best way to achieve this? Thank you guys.

Comment: Did you mean `verticals` in the initial dict? And why aren't you using a ModelForm?

Comment: Yes. I'm not using a ModelForm because there is other personalisation on the form.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
form = AdjustOffersForm(initial={
        'min_payout': offer_settings.min_payout,
        'max_payout': offer_settings.max_payout,
        'verticals': offer_settings.vertical.all().values_list('id', flat=True),
    })
```